# Download an SSL certificate from a remote website through a proxy

Tags: https, openssl, curl, wget, gnutls

I want a script checking my server's certificate. There are very good answers around here how to get this with `openssl s_client` or `gnutls-cli`, which works fine.... but NOT if you are behind a proxy! Doh!

I did not found a possibility to tell these tools to use a proxy. Openssl seems to have added the `-proxy` option some weeks ago (after 15 years!) but I cannot use this release because it's not yet available in my environment.

I also cannot install some fancy non standard tunneling software like `proxytunnel` (which I would really like to).

So is there ANY way to download a remote certificate from a web server with any standard tool like `curl`, `wget`, `openssl` or such?

Comment: If you want "standard" and cannot install stuff then how about telling your OS/version, huh?

Comment: It's a Debian. I don't know exactly which one because I have no direct access to the system.

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools that can be used to make a connection to a remote system through a CONNECT proxy.  I am not sure about the best one, but here are a couple examples [connect-proxy](https://bitbucket.org/gotoh/connect/) [corkscrew](https://packages.debian.org/sid/net/corkscrew), [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/), [proxytunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/intro.php).

connect-proxy looks promising though.  Apparently it offers you the option redirect to a local port instead of STDIN/STDOUT like most.

Here are some untested examples based on my reading of the [connect-proxy](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=connect&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%208%20jessie&format=html&locale=en) man pages.

```
# example
connect -H proxyserver:port remoteserver:port -p localport
# so to open a local port 4430 to Google via a squid proxy at 10.1.1.1
connect -H 10.1.1.1:3128 www.google.com:443 -p 4430
```